# Where to put extra view data that doesnt relate to view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel, organization

So, lets look at an example.  I have a Customer view model that looks like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}
}
```

On the UI there needs to be a drop down of customer types.  In order to populate this, something needs to go to the business layer or data layer and grab this list of customer types.

It seems to me that this logic doesn't really belong in CustomerViewModel since it isn't really customer data; only CustomerTypeId is.  So my question is, where in general (not necessarily in .net MVC, but general practice for the MVC view model concept) do people put this data access?

Is it acceptable to have a function in the view model itself called GetCustomerTypes()?

```
public class CustomerViewModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}

    public List<CustomerType> GetCustomerTypes() { ... }
}
```

Should I make a class/method in the business layer or a helper and import the code manually in the view to access this function? It seems to me like this would be code that clutters up the view and doesn't belong there.

```
@{
    using My.App.CustomerTypeHelper;
    var helper = new CustomerTypeHelper();
    var customerTypes = helper.GetCustomerTypes();
}

...

@Html.DropDownFor(x => x.CustomerTypeId, customerTypes)
```

The global Html helper eases this problem a bit in .Net, but I am looking for a more global solution conceptually that I can apply to PHP code, etc also.  PHP doesn't have the ability to cleanly have a static class that can be separated into small organized units with extension methods.  So any global helper is likely to get large and ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include `List<CustomerType>` in the model but do NOT implement function inside the model. Set the data from controller instead.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomerViewModel {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}

    public List<CustomerType> CustomerTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Assign data to ViewModel from Controller:

```
var model = new CustomerViewModel();
model.CustomerTypes = Customer.GetCustomerTypes();
```

Comment: That seems like it would get even more nasty.  It would result in huge action methods and controllers in more realistic scenarios where there is more than one lookup drop down.  Does it turn out like this in practice or am I just being overly paranoid?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a class that is 'shared' between models that has all the definitions of such data. I would go with something such as:

```
public static partial class StaticData
{
    public static List<CustomerType> CustomerTypes = new Lisr<CustomerType>
    {
        new CustomerType { Name = "Whatever", Discount = 10, ....... },
        new CustomerType { Name = "Another", Discount = 0, ........}
        // etc
    }
}
```

Notice this is a partial class so you can split this across files/folders in you project and have:

```
CustomerTypes.cs
SupplierTypes.cs
ProductTypes.cs
```

And anything else as separate files all building into a shared StaticData class that end up containing all your definitions for drop-downs and any other non-database information.

So then, in your view, you can populate your select options using StaticData.CustomerTypes.

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomerModel` (not *ViewModel*, because there is no *ViewModel* in MVC) is not the model of a `Customer`. It is the model used in the view `Customer`. If that view needs this information, it should be in that model.

It is not clear to me what that view does in your application, but it looks like some customer creation form. Just calling it `CustomerModel` doesn't explain the intent of the class very well. You might want to call your model `CreateModel`, used in `Create.cshtml` that is returned from the `Create()` method in the `CustomerController`. Then it makes sense to add the `CustomerType`s to this model: you need to have `CustomerType`s if you want to create a customer.